# How to get an array of values where columns match multiple criteria

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table of data similar to:

[image: Sample]

where I'd like to get just the `shapes` which match a set of given criteria (in this case `week=2` and `colour=blue`).

I can return the first result using `index` and `match` like:

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(C2:C14,MATCH($F$1&$F$2,A2:A14&B2:B14,0)))
```

but I'd like to return the all matching values (eg `square` and `triangle`) in to the range `F3:Fsomething`. This would preferably be done using a formula that returns a range and isn't "copied-down", as a list of all possible shapes isn't known beforehand.

How can I modify this formula to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works:

```
=FILTER (C2:C14, B2:B14=F2, A2:A14=F1)
```

Answer (score 0):

to do multiple criteria you want to use * like so

```
=FILTER (C2:C14, (B2:B14=F2) * (A2:A14=F1))
```

and if you want the results all in the same cell with a delimiter, use TEXTJOIN

```
=TEXTJOIN([DELIMETER],[IGNORE EMPTY TEXT],text1)

=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(C2:C14,(B2:B14=F2)*(A2:A14=F1)))
```